# The push responsive menus don't open themselves and don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Firstly, please, visit and check the demo: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/

I copied the source code of the demo to new folder and I created one Javascript, one CSS and one HTML.

I removed the parts of the menus and keep only the push responsive menus at the tags `<body class="cbp-spmenu-push"><nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">`.

I adjusted the size of the push responsive menus of the tags `showRightPush` and `showLeftPush` and removed the tags `section` of them too, so they can be moved with the tag `main`.

I also removed the section of the horizontal and vertical menus at the tag `<div class="main">`.

At the CSS file, I changed the proprieties of tags `main` and `container` (margin, padding, width and height), making the menus being separated and being moved to the top left and top right.

Finishing it, I loaded the HTML and I tried to click the push responsive menus. They don't open themselves and don't work.

You can check my demo of JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndL2nat1/

How to fix that?

Comment: One problem is you are not loading `classie.js` and there are more bugs in it.. if you are using Chrome. Open developer tools and checkout out the console.

Comment: @shakirthow Ah, then I have just copied the JS and CSS files in my folder and I modified quickly and I checked and I loaded the page, and the push responsive menus don't open themselves. Check my pack for testing: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tyts4lbbren8n2/Teste%20de%20Gus.zip?dl=0

Comment: I started the console at Chrome and it said: " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null". How to fix it?

Comment: also. to add external JS file in JSfiddle. you can find a CDN or a link to the file (can be a repository link too) and add click the "External Resources" on the left side and add the links . life is much easy that way :)

Comment: @shakirthow Ah, very easy. Check again: http://jsfiddle.net/ndL2nat1/1/

Comment: here fixed it for you [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ndL2nat1/2/). The problem is you removed several dom elements. but didn't comment any JS script that was using it :)

Comment: Which dom elements I have removed? @shakirthow

Comment: the buttons that has other nav animations

Comment: Ah, really, it was really `showTop.onclick` which prevents the menus from being open. Thank you a lot. It's fixed.

Comment: @shakirthow, is it possible to unify the two Javascript files in one javascript? And to unify them and two CSS files in one HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here fixed it for you [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ndL2nat1/2/). The problem is you removed several dom elements (the buttons that were operating other navbar animations) but didn't comment any JS script that was using it :). one example will be

```
showTop.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuTop, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showTop' );
};
```

but `showTop` is undefined as the dom element was removed

Comment: I included the classie.js in one Javascript. It\s inside the Javascript code at JSFiddle.